# nginx execute a command on shell and assign the result to a variable

Tags: nginx

I need to set a parameter

proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate      $dynamic_file_name

and the value of dynamic_file_name variable will be the output of a shell command. Can it be done using os.execute() ?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this? As you have explained it, this could easily cause more issues

Comment: The certificate filename changes based on certain events in the linux server and is not a constant. I need to set it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible in the way you asked for, but it should be possible with Lua
https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block